# What data does the compiler expects with "Date" type?

Tags: swift, date

I have following code on SWIFT with "Date()"

```
func howLongYouLive(date: Date) -> Double {
    let currentDate = Date()
    return currentDate.timeIntervalSince(date)
}

howLongYouLive(date: **?**)
```

When you call the function, what data you need to input? Screen attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIn2I.png)

I've tried to input any type of date I could think of but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why do you need an image of the screen?  You've described the question perfectly well in the text. The image is a waste of space and data. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for a list of the many reasons NOT to include images unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: When we assign the Date() to a constant it shows the format "Nov 3, 2022 at 10:51 AM". 
I've went through all the manuals I could search but found no info of this.

Comment: "what data you need to input" -- an instance of `Date`. For example: `howLongYouLive(date: Date())`

Comment: @RayceMiller `DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .iso8601), year: 2000, month: 1, day: 1).date!`

Comment: That doesn't explain why you included an image that adds no value to the question and is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you read the **fundamental basics of Swift**, here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

`When you call the function, what data you need to input?`, well you use a `Date` type.

Try this example code:

```
// calculate howLongYouLive in seconds 
func howLongYouLive(date: Date) -> Double {
    // some other calculations here I presume
    return Date().distance(to: date)
}
 
// a date, 99 years in the future from today
let futureDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 99, to: Date())!
print("\n---> futureDate: \(futureDate) ")

// the calculated howLongYouLive in seconds
let lifeExpectency = howLongYouLive(date: futureDate)  // <-- here
print("\n---> calculated howLongYouLive: \(lifeExpectency) seconds")

// the calculated howLongYouLive as a Date
let lifeDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(lifeExpectency)
print("\n---> howLongYouLive as date: \(lifeDate) ")

// the calculated howLongYouLive as a number of years
let years = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: Date(), to: lifeDate).year
print("\n---> howLongYouLive: \(years) years \n")
```

Comment: Of course that's not really a good way to get years from a date since it doesn't account for leap seconds and leap years. :)

Comment: yes I agree, it was just an example to show how to create a date and pass it to `howLongYouLive`.
             For completeness, I'll update my answer with a more robust code.